# Two parts of the view overlap, how can we show the overlap part of the content?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can we only show the overlap part of the two views? The other part of the view should not show.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `CGRectInterSection`

```
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake (x1, y1, a1, b1);
CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake (x2, y2, a2, b2);


CGRect intersectionRect = CGRectIntersection(rect1, rect2);
```

Comment: `CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1, rect2);` will return bool value. If two rects intersects then yes else no!!! Question is about finding intersects view

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question. The writer wants to know how to "show" only the overlapping portions of a view. You're answer still only provides a true/false answer to whether or not two views overlap. I'd have to research a little further, but the writer should be able to mask the view's with a shape that is equal to the over lapping area.